# Allowing Module/package customization with command line paramters without interfering with its users

Tags: python, argparse, python-3.3

I'm curious how I would do this in python. Imagine I have a module `spam.py` that I'd like to control the spamminess with the option `-‍-‍spam_more`.

How would I go about using argparse or some other parsing library that would still allow the main `ham.py` file to optionally use command line arguments as well while using the spam module.?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the argument handling stuff inside '`if __name__ == "__main__":`' Any code inside that `if` block will only run when the script is run from the command line or whatever, but not if it is imported as a module. e.g. Typing `$ python spam.py` in the command line will cause the block to be executed.

Here is an example using optparse (because I haven't used argparse before):

spam.py:

```
def do_stuff(spammy=False):
    if spammy:
        print "wow, this is spammy."
    else:
        print "i've seen spammier."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from optparse import OptionParser

    p = OptionParser()
    p.add_option("--spam_more", action="store_true", dest="spammy")
    (options, args) = p.parse_args()

    do_stuff(options.spammy)
```

ham.py:

```
import spam
# do optparse stuff...

spam.do_stuff()
```

This was when you use `--spam_more` on spam.py, `spammy` will be set to `True`. But ham.py knows nothing about this and can use it's own optparse stuff as well use use spam's function, `do_stuff()` because the code inside '`if __name__ == "__main__":`' never gets run when spam.py is imported as a module.

It is probably bad practice to put an `import` statement inside an `if` block, but it seems like the best way.